# Responsive images using CSS background-image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get these images to have the same `height` but an auto `width` while using `background-image` to set the image.

The first example shows the desired effect I was trying to get. Inline and same height.

2nd example is attempting the same effect using `background-image` on a div but these move onto a new line as they are block element.

3rd example is the same as 2nd but using spans as this is more similar to my real world issue. This collapses the width i assume because there is no actual content.

Thanks for the help all

```css
      .img-1 {
        content: url("https://via.placeholder.com/180x800");
      }
      .img-2 {
        content: url("https://via.placeholder.com/120x50");
      }
      .img {
        height: 200px;
      }

      .bg-img-span {
        display: inline-block;
        height: 100px;
        background-size: 200px 200px;
        border: solid 2px blueviolet;
      }

      .bg-image-div {
        display: block;
        height: 100px;
        background-size: 200px 200px;
        border: solid 2px blueviolet;
      }

      .bg-img-1 {
        background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/180x800");
      }
      .bg-img-2 {
        background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/120x50");
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>test</title>
    <style>

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>This is what i want - the same height and auto width</h2>
    <div>
      <img class="img img-1" alt="" />
      <img class="img img-2" alt="" />
    </div>

    <hr />

    <h2>Want these the same height and side by side</h2>
    <div>
      <div class="bg-image-div bg-img-1"></div>
      <div class="bg-image-div bg-img-2"></div>
    </div>

    <hr />
    <h2>Same as above but with spans</h2>
    <div>
      <span class="bg-img-span bg-img-1"></span>
      <span class="bg-img-span bg-img-2"></span>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So what is your actual problem and therefore question? You want to know how to scale background images?

Comment: Yes sorry for the bad phrasing of my message.

1. what are the negatives of using the technique above?

I haven't really seen much talk about using css content for images so I imagine its not widely used.
Thanks

Comment: Because there is really no need at all to do what you are doing. What is your initial problem you are trying to solve with this technique of yours?

Comment: ah ok thanks. The issue i was having originally was having 2 images set with "background-image" property and trying to have them set "height: Xpx" and "width: auto". 
I don't think width auto can be used on css background images and the container doesn't know about the size of the image inside. Without setting a width the containers collapse.

Comment: Edit your question with more information, not here as comment where no one will read it.

Comment: _“and trying to have them set "height: Xpx" and "width: auto". I don't think width auto can be used on css background images”_ - sounds like you might be looking for the [`background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) property? And if that is not what you meant, then give us a _proper_ [mre] of the problem you are actually facing.

Comment: edited the question to try and explain my issue